# Check if a binary number has a '0' or a '1' at a specific position

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, binary, decimal

I'd like to check if a binary number has a '0' or a '1' at a specific position.

example:

if the binary number is: 101000100

- checking at position zero (that is at
  the rightmost '0') should result in
  '0'.
- checking at position 2 should result
  in '1'.
- checking at position 3 should result
  in '0'.
- checking at position 6 should result
  in '1'.

  etc...

I'm coding in C, so obviously I could use sprintf / scanf and the likes, but I guess there must be something better (read: more time efficient / easier)!

What would be a good mechanism to do this?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267832/explanation-of-an-algorithm-to-set-clear-and-test-a-single-bit, and probably 20 others

Comment: I assume your number is stored as an int or a long, right? In that case, Wim's solution is perfect. If you already have it as a char array containing the chars '0' and '1', then you would just use `myCharArray[pos] == '1'`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This will filter out the bit you're looking for:

```
number & (1 << position)
```

If you really need a 1 or 0 response, you can use this to make it a boolean value:

```
!!(number & (1 << position))
```

Or even better (thanks [Vadim K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20845/vadim-k)):

```
(number >> position) & 1
```

Comment: Making it boolean does not make it 0 or 1. In C++ it makes it true/false in C the actual value that represents true is (!FALSE) which is not nesacerly 1.

Comment: You're right. **Vadim K.**s answer, `(number >> position) & 1`, is probably the most efficient one for the 0 or 1 response.

Comment: Martin York: The result of the unary `!` operator is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @caf: indeed.  iso 9899:1999: "The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares
unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int."  But I prefer `(number & (1 << position)) != 0` to `!!()`.

Answer (score 32):

This expression evaluates to the value of the bit you're looking for, either `0` or `1`:

```
(number >> position) & 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Warning: This code is not Standards-compliant.  [Bjarne Stroustrup says](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#unions), and he oughta' know, that, "Obviously, it's illegal to write one member and then read another..."  Nevertheless I leave this code up for educational purposes...

Here's an alternative that is useful when, say, reading a proprietary binary protocol off of a socket:

```
#include <cstdlib>


union Value
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char a_ : 1;
        unsigned char b_ : 1;
        unsigned char c_ : 1;
        unsigned char d_ : 1;
        unsigned char e_ : 1;
        unsigned char f_ : 1;
        unsigned char g_ : 1;
        unsigned char h_ : 1;
    } bits_;
    unsigned char charVal_;
};


int main()
{

    unsigned char someValue = static_cast<unsigned char>(0x42);
    Value val;
    val.charVal_ = someValue;

    bool isBitDSet = val.bits_.d_;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The standard only guarantees, roughly put, that the last union-member written to is accessible.

Comment: You write to an union member, then read from another one. This is undefined behavior per 9.5/1: "*In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.*". In this case, you cannot store the value of `charVal_` and the value of `bits_` in the union at the same time. What you *can* do is write to `charVal_`, read back what you wrote there, then write to `bits_`, and read what you wrote in `bits_`.

Comment: Fair enough, good to know.  That said, it still works for me. :)

Comment: This is a hack. It is a hack even within a single given platform. On top of that, it is not portable between platforms. I see absolutely no reason why anyone would use something like that instead of the obvious shift-and-test solution.

Comment: My reading of the standard is that when a union's member is written to, its other members take on an "implementation-defined value." It's not undefined behavior as far as I can determine.

Comment: @AndreyT - Because it is potentially faster. See my next comment regarding Standards compliance...

Comment: Regarding clause 9.5/1: As quoted above, only one member of a union can be active at a time. But the Standard goes on to clarify a bit: "[...]that is, the value of at most one of the data
members can be stored in a union at any time."  Seems to me this is simply defining the basic character of a union; nameley, that each member occupies the same space in memory.  The Standard does not say that once you have assigned a value to one member it cannot be accessed through another member. (continued...)

Comment: (continued from above) In other words, all the Standard says that if you do "union {int a; char* p;} g; g.a = 42; p = "Hello"; } the value 1 is no longer stored in the memory pointed to by &g.a.  The quote above says nothing about accessing the value in g through g.a.  But the Standard is clear that "Each data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct." Meaning, depending on the platform I suppose, they occupy the same location in memory.  Sure, it is platform Dependant.  But that doesn't make it bad.

Comment: Well, I take it all back.  On Stroustrup's site (http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#unions) he says explicitly "Obviously, it's illegal to write one member and then read another but people do that nevertheless (usually by mistake)."

Comment: I was certain that the standard made this undefined, but then I failed to find the relevant quote, so I'm not really sure right now. C99 makes the behavior implementation-defined. Note that accessing an object through an lvalue of type different than object's dynamic type is, with some exceptions, undefined (your code happens to be that exception though). In any case, the ordering of bitfields is implementation-defined, so an objective reason to avoid this misuse of unions remains.

Comment: The fundamental portion that makes it illegal in C standard (C89/90 and C99) is 6.5/7. It clearly states that memory occupied by object of one type cannot be accessed as object of another type (with some exceptions). In other words, *memory reinterpretation* is [almost] always illegal. Whether it is done through union, cast or by any other way is completely unimportant.

Comment: Indeed, but John's code happens to fall into those exceptions ("An object shall have its stored value accessed only  by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: [...], a character type"), i.e. the behavior is only implementation-defined in this particular case (per 6.5.2.3/5 in C99). For C++, the "character type" exception applies too, but 9.5/1 (the equivalent of C99's 6.5.2.3/5) doesn't make the behavior implementation-defined.

Comment: The standard would have been more practical to allow something like this with bit fields over simple data types or arrays thereof. Bit-shifts are so much less readable. And in fact this sort of thing does work on every compiler I've tried it on. Compiler writers are more pragmatic than standards organizations in cases like this. Just make it candidate for a future standard to reflect existing practice.

Comment: One thing that varies among common implementations is endianness, but often the first bitfield falls in the lsb position.